# AngularJS $location.path() breaks <audio> element?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, audio

I'm having trouble with AngularJS and can't figure out if I'm doing something wrong, or if it's a library bug. I have an  element on my page, and I'm changing the MP3 file via JavaScript. This works fine if I switch around within the same page. However, if you select a new playlist, I have it changing the hash path via $location.path("NewPlaylistName") to preserve state (so the path goes from /path/to/app/#/OldPlaylistName /path/to/app/#/NewPlaylistName). As soon as I do that, on all browsers, the  element breaks. It acts as it didn't have a src attribute.

Is there something special I need to do?

Comment: Not sure but if you're using a relative path that seems like it could cause problems.

Comment: $location.path doesn't preserve the state inside the ng-view. Did you have the audio element inside the ng-view?

Comment: The <audio> element is inside the ng-view, yes. Is there a better way to do this?